# Application crashes when activity starts in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, landscape-portrait

I have an application. The main activity has a page that has a button. This button only opens another activity. Here's the problem though. When I do this in the portrait mode, it works perfectly. Even after the activity has started, I can change it to landscape mode and it works fine. The application only crashes when the first activity is in landscape mode and I click the button to start the new activity. Any ideas how I should fix this? Why is it not working only during startup? and why is it working fine in landscape mode after I start it in portrait mode?

Another interesting thing I noticed, I deleted the layout xml files in the landscape folder and it doesn't crash anymore.

```
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034): Process: com.example.msapp2, PID: 7034
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.msapp2/com.example.msapp2.exercises.WorkoutBuddy}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-26 15:09:50.558: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Or some code that could help us look into this issue?

Comment: Definitely `onCreate()` needed to see what's happening.

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening. Do you want the layout xml file? or the the activity code? There is so much happening in the activity, it is hard to tell what might be crashing it. But it works smooth once it is started in portrait mode. i have no implemented onConfigurationChanged() method in my second activity and I also do not have a layout file for the activity in the landscape layout folder

Comment: Have a look at your LogCat. It has a lot to say. When the app crashes, go into the "error" mode of the LogCat and read carefully what is printed. :)
That will get you to the root cause of the problem. If you still cant fix it on your own, post it here and there will be someone to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are what's going on is that you are probably getting a reference to a layout element that exists in your portrait (/layouts/activity*.xml) layout but doesn't exist in your landscape layout (/layouts-land/activity*.xml).

For example,

```
Button button = (Button) findviewbyid(R.id.myButton);
```

Might work if you're in portrait because you have a `<Button />` element in it. But your landscape layout does not have the same element.

This leads to a `NullPointerException` which is the exception you got. It occurs when you try to access an object that has not been initialized. So look out for where you are doing that.

Comment: I literally copy-pasted my xml content from portrait to landscape and moved around the positions. All the elements are present in both landscape and portrait xml files. I'll double check though. That's a good point

Comment: Sometimes when you change layout files you need to clean your project. You can try that as well. And check that your android:id values haven't changed between files.

Comment: Also, do you know how I can change the layout file to be used when the orientation while the user is in the activity? I know it has something to do with onConfigurationChanged() method. Should i just do a setContentView(R.layout.landscape_layout) in my onConfigurationChanged() method/ Sorry, i'm new to all this.

Comment: Usually you don't have to use setContentView in onConfigurationChanged because onCreate usually gets call when the configuration changes